# getx Obx widget is not working in stream builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, stream-builder

i use stream buidler to show data from firebase, i am using getx for state managment. i want to show the updated value of a variable in stream builder, variabel initilize in getx controller to show his updated value i used Obx widget but it get error, kindly help me if someone know about this

i am trying to show my varibale value using obx widget in stream builder
**getx Controller**

```
RxBool check=false.obs;
var itemArr = [].obs;
RxDouble itemSum = 0.0.obs;
updateitemSum(double value){
itemSum.value=value;
}
RxDouble getItemSum(){
return itemSum;
}
updateCheck() {
check.value=true;
print('value is: ');
print(check);

}
```

**Main Screen**

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('Item')
                      .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data?.docs.length != 0) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              _controller.updateitemSum(0.0);
                              DocumentSnapshot itemTittle = snapshot.data
                                  ?.docs[index] as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
                              return Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                                //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                                child: Card(
                                  elevation: 6.0,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 8.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .height *
                                              0.1,
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceBetween,
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    child: Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                              6.0),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        itemTittle['tittle'],
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontSize: 18,
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .lightBlue),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Container(
                                                    child: Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                              6.0),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        'Income',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontSize: 18,
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .lightBlue),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Divider(
                                                color: Colors.grey,
                                                height: 25,
                                                thickness: 1,
                                                //indent: 5,
                                                //endIndent: 5,
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        StreamBuilder(
                                            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                .collection('Income')
                                                .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
                                                .where('itittle',
                                                    isEqualTo:
                                                        itemTittle['tittle'])
                                                .where('date',
                                                    isEqualTo: DateFormat()
                                                        .add_yMMM()
                                                        .format(selectedDate!))
                                                .snapshots(),
                                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>
                                                    snapshot) {
                                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                                return ListView.builder(
                                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                                    physics:
                                                        NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                                    itemCount: snapshot
                                                        .data?.docs.length,
                                                    itemBuilder:
                                                        (context, index) {
                                                      DocumentSnapshot ds =
                                                          snapshot.data?.docs[index] as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
                                                      double sum = 0.0;
                                                      sum = double.parse(_controller.getItemSum().toString()) +
                                                              double.parse(
                                                                  ds['income']);
                                                      _controller.updateitemSum(sum);

                                                        print('itemsum is:');
                                                        print(_controller.itemSum);
                                                      return Column(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                MainAxisAlignment
                                                                    .spaceBetween,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Container(
                                                                child: Padding(
                                                                  padding:
                                                                      const EdgeInsets
                                                                              .all(
                                                                          6.0),
                                                                  child: Text(
                                                                    ds['name'],
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        //  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                                        color: Colors.black),
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                              Container(
                                                                child: Padding(
                                                                  padding:
                                                                      const EdgeInsets
                                                                              .all(
                                                                          6.0),
                                                                  child: Text(
                                                                    ds['income'],
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                                        color: Colors.black),
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                          Divider(
                                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                                            height: 25,
                                                            thickness: 1,
                                                            //indent: 5,
                                                            //endIndent: 5,
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      );
                                                    });
                                              } else {
                                                return Container();
                                              }
                                            }),
                                         Container(
                                            height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .height * 0.1,
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                                      .spaceBetween,
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                  child: TextButton(
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      Navigator.push(
                                                          context,
                                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                                  AddIncome(
                                                                      itemtittle:
                                                                          itemTittle[
                                                                              'tittle'])));
                                                    },
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      'Add Income',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.bold,
                                                          fontSize: 14,
                                                          color:
                                                              Colors.lightBlue),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Container(
                                                  child: Padding(
                                                    padding:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                            6.0),
                                                    child: Obx(()=>
                                                        Text(
                                                          _controller.itemSum.toString(),
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.bold,
                                                              fontSize: 14,
                                                              color: Colors.black),
                                                        )
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),

                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                    } else {
                      return Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 6.0,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                'My Income',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 18,
                                                    color: Colors.lightBlue),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                'Income',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 18,
                                                    color: Colors.lightBlue),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Divider(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        height: 25,
                                        thickness: 1,
                                        //indent: 5,
                                        //endIndent: 5,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  // color: Colors.red,
                                  //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        child: TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () async {
                                            ToastMessage("Wait");
                                            Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) =>
                                                        AddIncome(
                                                            itemtittle:
                                                                'My Income')));
                                            await itemT.doc().set({
                                              "uid": uid,
                                              'tittle': 'My Income',
                                            });
                                            await itemT.doc().set({
                                              "uid": uid,
                                              'tittle': 'Expense',
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Add Income',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                color: Colors.lightBlue),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "0.0",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                color: Colors.black),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }),
```

[the error show om screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW5uv.png)

Comment: Obx(()=>
                                                        Text(
                                                          _controller.itemSum.toString(),
                                                          
                                                    ),

Comment: on the above code i get error